# Windows 10 download and execute file

Tags: c#, windows

Have here code snippet in C#
It should download and execute executable! On windows 7 works fine
On windows 10 it downloads file but does not start process

```
string droplocation = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData") + "/Temp/reader.exe";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://127.0.0.1/reader.exe", droplocation);
Process.Start(droplocation);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you need https instead of http.

Comment: Gonna try it out!

Comment: But i believe its not issue as it downloads file!

Comment: Perhaps the file is blocked. Look in the file properties dialog with File Manager. If it's blocked, it should say so at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Agree with Bent; my first thought is that because you've downloaded something (yes, even from the local machine) and windows is refusing to execute it because it's currently marked as blocked. If you think about how your program is potentially acting like every trojan/malware/virus you'll see the rationale behind having an O/S level block on files the user might not even know has been downlaoded onto their drive. Of course your next question will be "how can I defeat this protection, and download a random exe and launch it" - which if it was that simple, wouldn't be much protection..

Comment: Yes it was blocked, file size was 0 bytes, so it got stopped by security systems!

Comment: if you managed to solve your problem then please ad it as an ANSWER so other people can easily find it... not as a comment. Thanks.